# How can I use mixins or modules in my controllers in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mixins

I have some behavior in my controller that I pulled out into a module in order to test better and re-use it in a few places. Two questions about this:

1. Where is a good place to put my modules? They need to run in order to be available to the controllers, so I was thinking the `config/initializers/` directory. That seems a little suspect to me though. `lib/`?
2. How do I ensure the code gets run so the modules are available to `include` in my controllers?

Thank you kindly sirs.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. `lib/` is an excellent place for modules; much better than `config/initializers/`--at least in my opinion. If it's several modules, or one large one, you can also consider making it a plugin and placing it in `vendor/plugins`.
2. If you put it in `lib/`, you'll need to manually `require` the file. Rails, by default, does not autoload files in the `lib/` directory. You can place the require in one of your config files.

I usually put my additional autoloads in `config/application.rb`. Something like this should do the trick (assuming that your `.rb` file is in a directory called `lib/my_module`):

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/my_module"]
```

You have to make sure that your module is an actual `module` and not a `class`. Then, you can simply include it:

```
# lib/my_module/foobar.rb
module Foobar
  def foobar
    "Hello world!"
  end
end

# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foobar
end

# rails console
>> obj = MyModel.first
=> #<MyModel id: 1, ...>
>> obj.id
=> 1
>> obj.foobar
=> "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 2):

1) I like to put:
   my class extentions under app/extentions
   my modules under /app/mixins
   my services under /app/services

2) You can configure your application to load all of these in config/application.rb:
class extentions should be required right way
and the mixins and services can be added to your autoload path

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # require class extentions right now
    Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'extentions', "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'mixins', '{**}')]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '{**}')]
```

(I'm using rails 3)

Answer (score -1):

Try putting controller specific modules in `app/controllers`.  No `require` required.

Comment: Unless they are controllers, they shouldn't go in `app/controllers`. That defeats the purpose of the directory structure.

Comment: Agreed, Arbind Thakur's solution is best.  I'm not a fan of the /lib because in large projects that could definitely become unwieldy.  app/mixins with a hierarchy underneath is what we will most likely do.