# Where is the right place to put predefined class (e.g. String, Symbol) extensions in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to add `my_method` to the `Symbol` class, and be able to call `my_method` from `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def my_helper
    my_symbol.my_method
  end
end
```

Where is the most appropriate place to put:

```
class Symbol
  def my_method
    <some code here>
  end
end
```

?

Comment: I asked a similar question that got a few more detailed answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945124/how-can-i-use-mixins-or-modules-in-my-controllers-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that sticking your native class extensions in a new file in your `lib` folder and `require`-ing them in your `environment.rb` file should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a file named monkey_patches.rb (or similar) - so it's very obvious where the patches *are* - then load it with an initializer in config/initializers. That's what they're for!

Comment: Hi Cory! Where would you put the `monkey_patches.rb` file ? Do you mean to create a new file in `config/initializers` and put inside it `require 'monkey_patches'` ?