# Can't extend core Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to extend core classes and have no idea why the following fails when being called through the Rails 4 console:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

# lib/core_ext/string.rb
class String
  def test
    self + " some test"
  end
end

# lib/core_ext/array.rb
class Array
  def mean
    sum / size if sum && size
  end
end

# lib/core_ext/test.rb
class Test
  def test
    "some test"
  end
end
```

Rails console output:

```
1] pry(main)> test = Test.new
#<Test:0x007ff63971b588>
[2] pry(main)> test.test
"some test"
[3] pry(main)> "string".test
NoMethodError: private method `test' called for "string":String
from (pry):3:in `__pry__'
[4] pry(main)> [1,2,3].mean
NoMethodError: undefined method `mean' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
from (pry):4:in `__pry__'
```

Comment: I can work it in plain pry.

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes perhaps they are blocking the default way somehow

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425620/where-is-the-right-place-to-put-predefined-class-e-g-string-symbol-extension?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried `Array.class_eval do` and that didn't work either. Files are being loaded, otherwise I couldn't use the Test class.

Comment: Sorry, you were right, this did the trick: `Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }`. I assumed `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` would suffice.

Comment: If you put it in as an answer, then I'll mark as correct and upvote. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the following line to effectively require the files into your project

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
```

Taken from [In Ruby on Rails, to extend the String class, where should the code be put in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654517/in-ruby-on-rails-to-extend-the-string-class-where-should-the-code-be-put-in)

Comment: This simply DOES NOT WORK for me. I don't know why. Where exactly should this line go? I have the exact same configuration.

Comment: @Ariel I havent tried it personally, but I guess application.rb around(below) where Bundler#require is invoked would be a decent area.

Answer (score 4):

I would add the following:

```
# In config/initializers/require.rb:
require "core_ext/string" 
require "core_ext/array" 
require "core_ext/test"
```

And not modify config/application.rb's autoload_paths, which do not eager load your extensions. If a module or class is already loaded somewhere else, it won't extend it. For references, check these SO [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773266/confusing-about-autoload-paths-vs-eager-load-paths-in-rails-4/19852844#19852844)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you are interested in static methods (e.g. `String.test`) you you declare it as `def self.test`.